# Why is $\langle f,f\rangle > 0$ where $f \in C([0,1])$ for an inner product?

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces, inner-products

I was studying inner products from the book of Linear Algebra by Friedberg when I came across this example

[image: example]

The verification of the first three conditions are clear to me. But I couldn't get the last one i.e. $\langle f,f\rangle  > 0$ and why $f^2$ is bounded in some subinterval of $[0,1]$? And one more thing, why does this result in the truth of the last condition, i.e. why is the integral value greater than $0$?   Any explanation will be highly beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear that $f^2$ is nonnegative.

Since $f\ne0$, for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$, $f(x_0)\ne0$.

By continuity, $f(x_0) \ne0$ in a (small) interval around $x$.

(The above sentence is the meaning of "bounded away from zero".)

Integrating $f^2$ in that interval gives a (strictly) positive value.

Explicitly, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ (if $x_0=0$ or $1$ this is one-sided)

$$|f(x)|>\left|\frac{f(x_0)}2\right|$$

This leads to:

$$f^2(x) > \frac {f^2(x_0)}4 > 0$$

and therefore:

$$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx\ge\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f^2(x)dx>\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} 0 dx=0$$

Comment: And why **bounded on some subinterval of [0,1]** ?

Comment: Also why integrating $f^2$ in that interval is strictly positive ?

Comment: Bounded AWAY. I'll answer your second question by editing the answer.

Comment: How did you get the last inequality (i.e. after *therefore:*) ?

Comment: It is a property of integrals that $f(x)>0\implies\int_I f(x)dx>0$. Think about the definition: in each partition of our interval $f>0$, so the "area" $f(x) \Delta x$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Okay...I got it. Thankyou for your detailed explanation